# Proof of Dual Simplex Ratio Test

Tags: linear-programming, reference-request, simplex, dual-simplex

I have been trying to find proof of the ratio test for Dual Simplex, that is, selecting the variable that enters the base.

Specifically, I was interested in knowing why by making that choice, reduced costs stay positive.

Comment: Have you looked at proofs in introductory LP textbooks? It is covered, for example, in section 4.5 of the second edition of Luenberger, "Linear and Nonlinear Programming".